# What is wrong with my CASE statement on PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case

I'm coding a simple CASE to print on screen when a employee earn more of the AVG salary of the department. But I don't understand why I see on screen only one result when I want to check salary of 2 employees. I hope you understand my question. Thanks.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
  v_emp121_sal   employees.salary%TYPE;
  v_emp121_lname employees.last_name%TYPE;

  v_emp139_sal   employees.salary%TYPE;
  v_emp139_lname employees.last_name%TYPE;

  v_avgsal       employees.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT salary, last_name
  INTO   v_emp121_sal, v_emp121_lname
  FROM   employees
  WHERE  employee_id = 121;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE 121 SALARY IS: ' || v_emp121_sal);

  SELECT salary, last_name
  INTO   v_emp139_sal, v_emp139_lname
  FROM   employees
  WHERE  employee_id = 139;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE 139 SALARY IS: ' || v_emp139_sal);

  SELECT AVG(salary)
  INTO   v_avgsal
  FROM   employees
  WHERE  department_id = 50;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DEPARTMENT 50 AVG SALARY IS: ' ||
                          TRUNC(v_avgsal, 0));


  CASE
      WHEN 
          v_emp121_sal < v_avgsal THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SALARY OF EMP ' || v_emp121_lname ||
                               ' IS LESS THAN DEPARTMENT AVG');
      WHEN
          v_emp121_sal > v_avgsal THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SALARY OF EMP ' || v_emp121_lname ||
                               ' IS HIGHER THAN AVG DEPARTMENT');
      WHEN
          v_emp139_sal < v_avgsal THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SALARY OF EMP ' || v_emp139_lname ||
                               ' IS LESS THAN DEPARTMENT AVG');
      WHEN
          v_emp139_sal > v_avgsal THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SALARY OF EMP ' || v_emp139_lname ||
                               ' IS HIGHER THAN AVG DEPARTMENT');
  END CASE;

END;
/
```

[image]

Theory, I should receive on screen 
"SALARY OF EMP FRIPP IS HIGHER THAN AVG DEPARTMENT"
"SALARY OF EMP SEO IS LESS THAN AVG DEPARTMENT"

Comment: salary NUMBER(8, 2)

Comment: `rattlesnake`..can you post your working code here for others reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `case` expression returns one value. If you need separate outputs for two employees, use 2 `case` expressions so each of them returns its own value.

```
CASE
      WHEN 
          v_emp121_sal < v_avgsal THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SALARY OF EMP ' || v_emp121_lname ||
                               ' IS LESS THAN DEPARTMENT AVG');
      WHEN
          v_emp121_sal > v_avgsal THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SALARY OF EMP ' || v_emp121_lname ||
                              ' IS HIGHER THAN AVG DEPARTMENT');
END CASE;

CASE
      WHEN
          v_emp139_sal < v_avgsal THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SALARY OF EMP ' || v_emp139_lname ||
                               ' IS LESS THAN DEPARTMENT AVG');

      WHEN
          v_emp139_sal > v_avgsal THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SALARY OF EMP ' || v_emp139_lname ||
                               ' IS HIGHER THAN AVG DEPARTMENT');
END CASE;
```

You might want to add a condition for `=` as well so you can avoid a `null` output when `>` or `<` condition fails.

Comment: @Rattlesnake - To further clarify why the original code doesn't produce the output the OP wanted: A `case` expression is evaluated until the first `when` condition is true. Once a `when` condition is true, the `then` value is returned/action is taken, and the whole `case` expression is exited - no further evaluations or assignments take place.

Comment: I was thinking about it and I tryed to do the same thing with IF sentence but I received the same results (one employee condition) Is there any way to check salary of employees within the same CASE or IF sentence? Thanks for reply.

Comment: @Rattlesnake - it is possible. `WHEN v_emp_121_sal > avg THEN` <do both PUT_LINE actions AT THE SAME TIME>, not in separate WHEN branches.

Comment: understood. So I should write something like "WHEN v_emp121_sal AND v_emp131_sal < v_avgsal THEN DBMS...."? Thanks.

Comment: @Rattlesnake - I am not sure I understand the requirement. You pick two employees, both may have salary greater than the average for the ENTIRE DEPARTMENT then you want a message saying both are greater than average? Then yes, `WHEN sal1 > avg and sal2 > avg then PRINT MESSAGE1 (about BOTH employees) WHEN sal1 > avg and sal2 < avg then PRINT MESSAGE2` etc. What do you want to print when a salary is exactly equal to the average?

Comment: Yes! You has answered my question. I wanted to write "WHEN sal1 > avg AND sal2 > avg THEN...". Thanks for your time!!! I will continue practicing PLSQL :)